# Query is not returning proper values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below which is a mammoth:

```
DECLARE @Start Date, @End Date, @DaySpan int, @UserId int, @ProjectId int
SET @Start = '7/08/2014 12:00 AM -05:00';
SET @End = '7/27/2014 12:00 AM -05:00';
SET @DaySpan = 1;
SET @UserId = 102;
SET @ProjectId = 2065;

WITH T(StartDate, EndDate)
    AS (
        SELECT @Start StartDate, DATEADD(DAY, @DaySpan - 1, @Start) EndDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate) StartDate, DATEADD(DAY, @DaySpan, EndDate) FROM T WHERE DATEADD(DAY, @DaySpan, EndDate) <= @End
    )
    SELECT convert(datetimeoffset, T.StartDate) StartDate, T.EndDate, ISNULL(Completes, 0) Completes, SUM(h.Hours) Hours, SUM(h.Hours) / NULLIF(Completes, 0) HoursPerRecruit,
    ISNULL(Completes, 0) / NULLIF(SUM(h.Hours), 0) RecruitsPerHour
    FROM T LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT StartDate, EndDate, COUNT(r.Id) Completes
        FROM Respondents r JOIN T st ON r.RecruitedOn >= st.StartDate AND r.RecruitedOn < DATEADD(day, 1, st.EndDate)
        WHERE r.RecruitingStatus = 7 
        AND RecruitedBy = @UserId 
        AND r.ProjectId = @ProjectId -- **REMOVE Line If you just want by User**
        GROUP BY st.StartDate, st.EndDate
    ) c ON T.StartDate = c.StartDate AND T.EndDate = c.EndDate
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT st.StartDate, st.EndDate, SUM(Hours) Hours
            FROM T st JOIN TimeEntries te ON te.Date >= CONVERT(DATE, st.StartDate) AND te.Date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,CONVERT(DATE, st.EndDate)),1)
                JOIN Users u ON te.HarvestUserId = u.HarvestId 
                --JOIN Projects PR ON te.HarvestProjectId = PR.Id
                WHERE u.Id = @UserId 
                GROUP BY st.StartDate, st.EndDate
            ) h ON T.StartDate = h.StartDate AND T.EndDate = h.EndDate
    GROUP BY T.StartDate, T.EndDate, Completes
    ORDER BY T.StartDate
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

It returns results like below:

```
StartDate   EndDate Completes   Hours   HoursPerRecruit RecruitsPerHour
2014-07-10 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  2014-07-10  6   3.00    0.500000    2.00000000000000000000000000
```

It works great.. But now I want to limit the hours returned by project. So in the query you will see a line that is commented out that `JOIN Projects PR ON te.HarvestProjectId = PR.Id`. When I add that bit of code it completely messes up the calculations and returns nothing. Like so:

```
StartDate   EndDate Completes   Hours   HoursPerRecruit RecruitsPerHour
2014-07-10 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00  2014-07-10  6   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

What am I missing that is is making the HoursPerRecruit and RecruitsPerHour be null? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: without having the sample data for each table that is involved here, it is very tough to answer your question, the only thing people can point you is a direction but they cannot answer you

Comment: I understand hopefully that will help me figure it out then I can check the best advice as the answer and then provide my solution in a edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't a complete answer, but I can't format code in a comment.

Look at just this bit of code, and execute it with some valid value for the parameter:

```
    SELECT st.StartDate, st.EndDate, SUM(Hours) Hours
    FROM T st JOIN TimeEntries te ON te.Date >= CONVERT(DATE, st.StartDate) AND te.Date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,CONVERT(DATE, st.EndDate)),1)
        JOIN Users u ON te.HarvestUserId = u.HarvestId 
        --JOIN Projects PR ON te.HarvestProjectId = PR.Id
        WHERE u.Id = @UserId 
        GROUP BY st.StartDate, st.EndDate
```

Then un-comment the commented line.  Does it return no rows?   I'm guessing that will be the case based on what you describe.

If so, then look at the results of this:

```
SELECT * FROM Projects
```

and see if you can figure out why no rows from the Projects table are joining to the TimeEntries table.  Maybe you're joining on the wrong columns, or there's a mis-match in the data format.

Comment: This got me there thanks. The problem was with PR.Id should have been PR.HarvestId

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to limit the results the condition should be in the `Where` clause below your commented out join. If your Project.ID is directly linked to TimeEntries.HarvestProjectId with no other conditions you should be able to change the line

`WHERE u.Id = @UserId`

to:

`WHERE u.Id = @UserId and te.HarvestProjectId=@ProjectID`